# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to run this loop in app delegate to initialize core data but it always crashes after a random number of runs without changing any of the code and it's always at the managedContext.save(). I check the data it's trying save when it crashes and there's nothing that should be a problem.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= bodyCount; i++){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("BItem", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let newItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    newItem.setValue(itemHref, forKey: "href")
    newItem.setValue(itemTitle, forKey: "title")
    newItem.setValue(itemUrl, forKey: "url")
    newItem.setValue(itemIndex, forKey: "index")
    newItem.setValue(itemSubTitle, forKey: "subTitle")
    newItem.setValue(itemImgSrc, forKey: "imgSrc")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    }catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save body item \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

The Errors:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'

Comment: Is this loop on a background thread or main thread?

Comment: @LyndseyScott a background thread

Comment: If you're simultaneously accessing the persistent store coordinator from the main thread and background thread, that's what's causing the crash.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I did find a section in the main thread that's trying to fetch the data before this background process finished. Would there be a way to make sure the main bit of code happened after this bit finished?

Comment: Just fix your threading, create a context for the background thread, don't try to cheat by having the main thread wait